# Is there way to use FirebaseUI in xamarin mobile app?

Tags: xamarin, firebaseui

Is there way to use FirebaseUI in xamarin mobile app?
If not, can we create entirely separate authentication module in Java/kotlin and rest application part in xamarin?

Comment: https://medium.com/step-up-labs/firebaseui-for-net-wpf-uwp-xamarin-553abc5da3f

Comment: There is no support for Xamarin forms.  From the article " FirebaseUI is currently only available for WPF on .NET Core 3.1, but UWP and Xamarin are on the roadmap."